# Integration of a natural logarithmic function using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, substitution

The function is 
$$\int \frac{1}{1+ \sqrt{2x}} dx$$

Using $u=1+\sqrt{2x}$, $du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}}dx$. Which gives us
$$\sqrt{2x}\int\frac{1}{u}du $$
The final answer of this would give $\sqrt{2x}\ln|1+\sqrt{2x}|$, but when I checked my answer the correct answer is $\sqrt{2x}-\ln|1+\sqrt{2x}|$.

Comment: @metamorphy Because then $du=dx$

Comment: dude, i don't want to make you sad, but how did you put $\sqrt{2x}$ outside integral? $\sqrt{2x} = u - 1$. That's why you have wrong answer.

Comment: It is not allowed to factor $x$ (or whatever is the name of the variable) out of the integral.

Comment: @EugeneSirkiza No hard feelings, even though my final is tomorrow lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have solved the problem is wrong. When you make the substitution

$$u = 1+\sqrt{2x}$$

$$\implies x = \frac{(u-1)^2}{2}$$
$$\implies dx = (u-1)du$$

Therefore the integral then is:

$$\int \frac{u-1}{u} du$$
$$= u - \log(|u|) + C$$
$$= 1+\sqrt{2x} - \log(|1+\sqrt{2x}|) +C$$
$$=\sqrt{2x} - \log(|1+\sqrt{2x}|) +C'$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=1+\sqrt{2x}$, then 
$$x=\frac{1}{2}(u-1)^2$$ and 
$$dx=(u-1)du$$
Therefore
$$\begin{align}\int \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2x}}dx&=\int \frac{1}{u}(u-1)du \\
&=\int \left( 1-\frac{1}{u}\right)du \\
&=u-\log |u|+c \\
&=(1+\sqrt{2x})-\log(1+\sqrt{2x})+c\end{align}$$